# Android Studio 1.0 Project structure

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have recently migrated to Android Studio 1.0 from Eclipse. I managed to export an android project and add it as a module in Android Studio. 
Every time I shut down Android Studio or restart it, the project structure keeps disappearing and the Project explorer says "**Nothing to show**". So I am forced to add the modules again and the respective libraries. 
Why is this the case and how do I get Android Studio to save the state of the structure on closing the IDE?

Comment: Make sure you've properly migrated the project, as described here: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html. If it doesn't work for you, you may consider submitting a bug report describing your issue.

Comment: I did follow the migration directions in the link. I haven't seen any other complaint on the same, so I can't be too sure if it is a bug